Let $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow[-1,1]$ and let $g_n(x)=\int_0^xf_n(t)dt$. There is $g_{n_k}\rightarrow g$ in $C([0,1])$ where $g$ is absolutely continuous
Let $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of measurable functions with $|f_n(x)|\leq 1$ for ae $x$. Let
$$g_n(x)=\int_0^xf_n(t)dt$$
Show that there exists an absolutely continuous $g$ and a subsequence $n_k\rightarrow \infty$ such that $g_{n_k}\rightarrow g$ in $C([0,1])$.
I showed that $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, and this produces a uniformly convergent subsequence $g_{n_k}\rightarrow g.$ I am not sure how to show $g$ is absolutely continuous. I know that the uniform limit of absolutely continuous functions is not absolutely continuous in general. If you try and do the 3-$\epsilon$ trick here I don't think it gets you anywhere since you'd have to bound terms of the form $\sum_{j=1}^N|g(b_j)-g_{n_k}(b_j)|$ where $N$ can be anything, and $|g(b_j)-g_{n_k}(b_j)|<\epsilon$ is insufficient to deal with that.
I am taking a first class in measure theory, but I found this problem elsewhere so it's possible I need something here that I haven't learned.

Just not that $|g_{n_k}(x)-g_{n_k}(y)|\leq |x-y|$, So, $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq |x-y|$, hence $g$ is absolutely continuous.

For ease of notation we redenote the subsequence $(g_{n_k})$ of $g_n$ by $\varphi_n(x)=\int_0^x f_n$.
The key is to note that $\varphi_n$ is "uniformly" absolutely continuous:
Given $\epsilon>0$, if $([a_i,b_i])_{i=1}^N$ are $N$ disjoint intervals with $\sum_{i=1}^{N} (b_i-a_i)<\epsilon$,
then for all $n$, $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} |\varphi_n(b_i)-\varphi_n(a_i)|=\sum_{i=1}^{N} |\int_{a_i}^{b_i} f_n|\le \sum_{i=1}^{N} (b_i-a_i)<\epsilon.  $$
Now let $\varphi_n\to\varphi $ uniformly on $C[0,1]$.
For disjoint intervals $([a_i,b_i])_{i=1}^N$, we can estimate
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N} |\varphi(b_i)-\varphi(a_i)|\le \sum_{i=1}^{N} \Big( |\varphi(b_i)-\varphi_n(b_i)|+ |\varphi_n(b_i)-\varphi_n(a_i)|+|\varphi(a_i)-\varphi_n(a_i)|\Big)   $$ for all $n$.
For $\epsilon>0$, if $\sum_{i=1}^{N} (b_i-a_i)<\epsilon$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} |\varphi_n(b_i)-\varphi_n(a_i)|<\epsilon $$
for all $n$ (and number of intervals, $N$).
Then we select the index $n$ to make $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \Big(|\varphi(b_i)-\varphi_n(b_i)|+|\varphi(a_i)-\varphi_n(a_i)|\Big)<\epsilon.$$
This can be achieved since the above summation is finite.
To sum up, for all $N\in\mathbb Z_+$, $N$ disjoint intervals $([a_i,b_i])_{i=1}^N$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{N} (b_i-a_i)<\epsilon$,
we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} |\varphi(b_i)-\varphi(a_i)|<2\epsilon.  $$
This implies $\varphi$ is absolutely continuous.
